# Do I have 3rd gen or 4th gen PCIe slots?

Tags: motherboard

I have a ROG Strix GA35DX computer, prebuilt from Best Buy. Bought it in 2021, here is what the inside looks like, I have disconnected the GPU:

[image]

I have 2 PCIe slots behind the silver looking panels near the bottom, the one on the top houses the following SSD (which came with the PC), and that is where my OS is stored:

[image]

It is a 3rd gen, 512GB. I want to buy another internal NVMe SSD as I have run out of space on the original.

Not sure whether to buy a 3rd gen or a 4th gen as I am unsure whether or not my motherboard supports 4th gen. I asked around and people want to know the motherboard model and I have no idea, although the CPU is an AMD Ryzen 5900X and apparently does support 4th gen.

What motherboard is this? Does it support 4th gen PCIe NVMe M.2 internal SSDs? I know that 4th gen is backwards compatible and will work either way, but why spend the extra money if I can't run it to its full potential.

UPDATE: Ran CPU-Z, this was the output under Mainboard:

[image]

Comment: https://www.hwinfo.com/

Comment: Impossible to tell from your screenshots. Use software to identify the capabilities of your system. However, a machine from 2021 (or earlier more than likely) is likely to be at best PCIe 4. You took a screenshot of everything but the model of the motherboard. It’s this product line I presume [here](https://rog.asus.com/desktops/full-tower/rog-strix-ga35-series/spec/)?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, that product line. And I can't find the model anywhere on the motherboard. Might be under the CPU cooling stuff for all I know. But thanks, I will go the software route.

Comment: https://rog.asus.com/uk/desktops/full-tower/rog-strix-ga35-series/spec/ suggests you have an Asus X570 motherboard which *could* have 2 PCIe x16 4.0 slots and various gen 4 M.2 slots. Hard to know without the exact motherboard model. You can get motherboard info using [CPU-Z](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html)

Comment: You don’t need the motherboard model, ASUS has the specifications, listed on the page I provided

Comment: @Ramhound that page just says it has PCIe 4.0 slots for graphics cards and 2 M.2 connectors but doesn't actually tell you what generation the m.2 slots are. You can guess they *should* be 4.0 but the motherboard manual would tell you for sure.

Comment: @Mokubai Updated my question to include the CPU-Z output, says PCIe 4.0.

Comment: @PaulG - Post an answer instead of editing your question to include the answer to your question.  The time for the CPU-Z information was when you original submitting the question, of course if you had ran CPU-Z prior to submitting the question, you likely woudln't have submitted the question.